# Wait for effect in effector

Tags: javascript, effector

Is there more "native" way for effector instead of `waitForTask`?

```js
import { createEffect } from 'effector'
const runTestTask = createEffect({
    async handler (name) {
        // Simulating long task 
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
        return { name };
    }
});

function waitForTask (cb) {
    if (runTestTask.pending.getState()) {
        const unsub = runTestTask.doneData.watch(() => {
            unsub();
            cb({ ... });
        });
    } else {
        cb({ ... });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Effect itself has four fields
.done - an event that's emitted as soon as the handler has been resolved
.fail - an event that's emitted as soon as the handler has been rejected
.finally - an event that's emitted as soon as the handler has been finished

if we are talking about dataflow the simplest cases will be the following:

```
const $testStore = createStore({})
*here is your effect snippet*
$testStore.on(runTestTask.done, (prevState, payload) => payload)
```

OR

```
forward({
from: runTestTask.fail,
to: showFailPopup
})
```

I wrote an [article](https://dev.to/yanlobat/effector-s-beginner-guide-3jl4) to resolve common misunderstandings

Comment: I need method that will return current state (fulfilled promise) if task was executed some time ago or promise for `done` event if task still executing.

Comment: If you need the last state of fulfilled promise then you'll need to use sample (`source` field) 
Like
```
sample({
source: runTestTask.done, // last triggered `.done`
clock: someEvent, // event to trigger sample
fn?: SomeFn, // combinator function for processing payload from source and clock,
target:  SomeUnit // store event effect (e.g. showFailPopup)
})